# Impossible to create SIFT detector and extractor

Tags: c++, opencv, sift

I'm trying to detect SIFT keypoints, using this code:

```
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"

[...]

Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create( "SIFT" );
vector<KeyPoint> keyPoints;
detector->detect( image, keyPoints );
The problem is that my detector pointer points to nowhere after that last line, and no error is shown in the console.
```

I'm using QtCreator and my .pro file contains:

```
LIBS += -lopencv_nonfree
CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv
```

so my makefile contains:

```
LIBS          = $(SUBLIBS) -lopencv_nonfree [...]  /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so [...]
```

There is no error when loading the libraries.

I've installed opencv using those instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to call `cv::initModule_nonfree();` before doing anything else.